# How to test the ion-input in ionic with angular?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ionic-framework, events, input

i am using angular and the ionic framework for my application i have an simple form in my application because i am using TDD i want to test the behaviour that when user enter that data in the input field i can access it using the component . I am using the angular reactive forms to get the data .

my html code

```
        <form [formGroup]="logInFormGroup" (submit)="onSubmit()">

          <ion-item>
            <ion-label position="floating">UserName</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" data-test="inputUserName"  formControlName="userName"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>

          <ion-item>
            <ion-label position="floating">Password</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="password" data-test="inputPassword" formControlName="password"></ion-input> 
          </ion-item>
               
          <ion-button data-test="btnLogIn" type="submit">LogIn</ion-button>

        </form>


      </ion-card-content>
```

this is my test case

here inputUserName gets the hold of the ion-input element from the dom
in my test case i am trying to get the input field in the ion-input by using the getInputElement method of ion-input and change the value then fire input event so new value is populated in the ion-input and formcontrol but it didn't work it still have the initial value .

```
 beforeEach(() => {
  inputUserName = el('[data-test="inputUserName"]');
  inputPassword = el('[data-test="inputPassword"]');
  btnLogIn = el('[data-test="btnLogIn"]');

  inputEvent = new Event('input');

  });

 it('should have the value in the userNameControl ' , () => {

  inputUserName.getInputElement().then(input => {

    input.value = userNameStub ;

    input.dispatchEvent(inputEvent);

    fixture.detectChanges();

    userNameControl = component.logInFormGroup.controls['userName'];

    expect(userNameControl.value).toEqual(userNameStub);
  });
```

this is my component code where i am using reactive form

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

 @Component({
 selector: 'app-login',
 templateUrl: './login.page.html',
 styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})


export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

     logInFormGroup: FormGroup ;

     constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit() {

       this.logInFormGroup = this.fb.group({
      'userName': ['asdfa'],
      'password': ['asdfasd']
     });

  }

  onSubmit(){
       console.log(this.logInFormGroup);
     }

}
```

in my component i have console out the output when user click submit the values are are correct when i manually test the code but my test case is failing the value in userName remains the same which i initialised in formbuilder .

Comment: Hello, maybe if you make your test case in fakeAsync(...) and do a tick() between     input.dispatchEvent(inputEvent); and fixture.detectChanges(); ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using early versions of Ionic, you should dispatch event 'ionChange' instead of 'input'. If you are using newer versions of Ionic you should dispatch on your test event 'ionInput'.

Plus, as you're using Angular, you should set up the component on beforeEach, so it gets created and its lifecycle processed.

Below an example of a test that is passing:

field:

```
<ion-input #filterInput
  name="description"
  formControlName="description"
  label="Description"
  (ionInput)="doSomethingWithValue($event.target['value'])">
</ion-input>
```

test:

```
let component: MyComponent;
beforeEach(() => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [MyComponent],
        imports: [IonicModule.forRoot(), ReactiveFormsModule],
        //teardown: { destroyAfterEach: false }
    }).compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FilteredListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
});

    it('should do something with value', async () => {
        spyOn(component, 'doSomethingWithValue').and.callThrough();
        const input = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('ion-input');
        expect(input).toBeTruthy();
        input.value = 'A';
        input.dispatchEvent(new Event('ionInput'));
        expect(component.searchValue).toHaveBeenCalledWith('A');
    });
```